# File cannot be found using open()

Tags: python, file

The code is not finding the notepad document, please help

```
SEND_REPORT_TUPLE = ('wet', 'water', 'liquid')
#make a list from the input
input_list = answer.split(" ")
#And then the use any function with comprehension list
if any(e in SEND_REPORT_TUPLE for e in input_list):
    file = open('Notepad', 'r')
    print = file
```

Comment: What is answer? where is it defined?  What do you expect input_list to be?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your file is in the same directory as your python script or put a full path to it. You should also put the file extension in the name

i.e.

file = open('Notepad.txt', 'r')